# Get number of forks, downloads and pulls for Git repository

Tags: git, github, repo

I have a github repository and I would like to know the number of times it was forked and download and `git pulled`. We need these information for a statistical way of analysing our repo. It is a public repo and I have all the access that I could need.

I am not sure if we could get that info from GitHub itself.

Answer (score 1):

On GitHub, about the **forks**, you can accomplish this by the API `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/forks` as documented here https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#forks .

About the /orgs/{org}/repos and **pulls** the API `/orgs/{org}/repos` is documented at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#downloads .

Comment: Thanks for this, I got fork information from this.
Any idea on how to number of pulls or downloads?

Comment: I answered this question in the main answer. Read carefully the documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#downloads . Please accept my answer if it suites for you. Thx